# i want product page sidebar as related products instant of upsell products

Tags: product, related-products, upselling

here is my `catalog.xml` block:

```
 <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml" />
```

here is my `view.xml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `catalog.xml` find the `catalog_product_view` section

```
<reference name="right">
 <block type="catalog/product_list_related_right" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
</reference>
```

call related product :

```
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
```

Comment: yeah it worked. thanks lot Nikunj vadariya